# Getting file not found exception with PrintWriter and File

Tags: java, file, io, output, printwriter

```
public static void generateOutput() {
    File file = new File ("C:/Users/me/Desktop/file.txt");
    PrintWriter outputFile = null;
    outputFile = new PrintWriter(file);
}
```

Above is my code, I am trying to make a PrintWriter that writes to a file I have made on my desktop called file.txt, however I am getting the error "unhandled exception type, file not found exception". I have looked at other posts and I'm unsure why I am still getting this error. I have also tried doing so without the File object. I was hoping for some guidance as to where I went wrong

Comment: If file exists, then add try-catch or add throws exception in method signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important idea you have to understand here, is that your file may:

1. not be found;
2. have its descriptor locked (which means, that some other process uses it);
3. be corrupted;
4. be write-protected.

In all above cases, your Java program, triggering OS Kernel, will crush, and the exception will happen at the **runtime**. In order to avoid this accident, Java designers decided (and well they did), that `PrintWriter` should throw (meaning, it is a possibility to throw) `FileNotFoundException` and this should be a checked exception at compile time. This way developers will avoid more serious run-time problems, like program crush crush.

Hence, you either have to:

1. `try-catch` in your method that PrintWriter; or
2. throw the exception one level up.

I think, your question was about why *that happens*. Here is the answer for both - (1) why? and (2) how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Java has an exception catch mechanism that helps you program better. You will have to handle an exception `FileNotFoundException` to warn that what will happen if the program cannot find your file Or you can `throws` this exception. I recommend learning about exception handling in Java.
This code can help you

```
public static void generateOutput() {
        File file = new File ("C:/Users/me/Desktop/file.txt");
        PrintWriter outputFile = null;
        try {
            outputFile = new PrintWriter(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // Handle if your file not found
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Or

```
public static void generateOutput() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File ("C:/Users/me/Desktop/file.txt");
        PrintWriter outputFile = null;
        outputFile = new PrintWriter(file);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file exists in the given location, you need one of the following,

> public static void generateOutput() throws Exception {... Your code ...}

Or

```
try {
//Your code 
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnne) {
// Precise exception catching example
}
catch(Exception e) {
// Not required, but adding it to catch any other exception you might face
}
```

You can always use precise exception in throws/catch.  You need it because, `PrintWriter` can has compile time exception. Basically, it means if file is not found then it can throw exception and it is known at compile time. Hence you need to use one of the approach.

In addition to that, you make 2 lines into 1 as follows,

> PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);

You don't need to initialize the output object to null, unless you have it on purpose.